# Is it possible to Center the contents of a column on the horizontal space, while maintaining a horizontalAlignment of start

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable called DetailTile, which is a Row with an Icon, 16dp horizontal space and a text, this DetailTile, I have 3 of, living in a column, and when I set the Row's `horizontalArrangement` to Start, it sets all the DetailTiles to start at the same point on the x-axis, however, I want to Center them while maintaining their start alignment, so, I try changing the Arrangement to Center, and it rightfully centers them on the screen's x-axis, but now they don't start on the same point, they all have different starts as they are truly centered, but I don't want this behaviour, I want them to be centered while maintaining their Start arrangement

**CODE**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println(savedInstanceState?.size());
        setContent {
            BusinessCardTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = colorResource(R.color.primary)
                ) {
                    BusinessCard(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(20.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BusinessCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier)
        `Jumbo-tron`()
        Details(/*Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)*/)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun `Jumbo-tron`(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = colorResource(R.color.black))
                .size(100.dp),
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.android_logo),
                contentDescription = null,
            )
        }
        Text("Full Name", fontSize = 26.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.W300)
        Text("Cross-Platform Full-Stack Developer", fontSize = 14.sp)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Details(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        DetailTile(icon = Icons.Rounded.Phone, detail = "+123 45 678 9000")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        DetailTile(icon = Icons.Rounded.Share, detail = "https://g.dev/devName")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        DetailTile(icon = Icons.Rounded.Email, detail = "devName@gmail.com")
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailTile(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, icon: ImageVector, detail: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
    ) {
        Icon(icon, contentDescription = null)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Text(detail, textAlign = TextAlign.Justify)
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFB39DDB)
@Composable
fun BusinessCardPreview() {
    BusinessCardTheme {
        BusinessCard(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(20.dp),
        );
    }
}
```

**START ALIGNMENT**

[image]

**CENTER ALIGNMENT**

[image]

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can wrap `Details()` content in a `Box` and apply `CenterAlignment` like below and Column's horizontalAlignment as Start:

```
@Composable
private fun Details(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = modifier.wrapContentWidth()
        ) {
            DetailTile(icon = Icons.Rounded.Phone, detail = "+123 45 678 9000")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            DetailTile(icon = Icons.Rounded.Share, detail = "https://g.dev/devName")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            DetailTile(icon = Icons.Rounded.Email, detail = "devName@gmail.com")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailTile(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, icon: ImageVector, detail: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
    ) {
        Icon(icon, contentDescription = null)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Text(detail, textAlign = TextAlign.Justify)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that but it doesn't work , I also just copied yours and dumped it in mine, doesn't do it either

Comment: Okay issue was in width assignment. Applying fillMaxWidth() in Column and Row didn't allowed Box to align content in center. Please check updated answer

Comment: Replacing `fillMaxWidth()` with `wrapContentWidth()` worked fine